# Drag and drop not working, desktop and Thunderbird (Ubuntu 20.04.01)

Tags: 20.04, thunderbird, drag-and-drop

The point es very simple: in Ubuntu 20.04.01 Drag and drop is not working either in desktop and Thunderbird.
Is there a way I can fixing this?
besides this, it's very cool!
Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a step-by-step example in your Question above so we can duplicate the problem?